# AngularJS: Can't access $valid on input from directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angular-fullstack

I have a simple application based on the angular-fullstack project, with lots of very similar input fields.

**Aim:** make input fields dynamic, move them to a directive so that input field code is moved out of template - better to maintain, less repetition of code.

**Problem:** I can't access values like `$valid` on the dynamically generated field, as they're not set

I have a very simple directive:

```
'use strict';
const angular = require('angular');

export default angular.module('testApp.inputText', [])
  .directive('inputText', function() {
    return {
      template: require('./inputText.html'),
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: false,
      transclude: true,
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.fieldName = attrs.name;

      }
    };
  })
  .name;
```

With a simple template:

```
<input
  type="text"
  name="fieldName"
  class="uk-input"
  ng-model="build.justTest.view[fieldName].value"
  >
```

Which I call like this:

```
<form name="build.justTest.view" novalidate>
  <input-text name="new-test-input"></input-text>
</form>
```

When I use ng-inspector to inspect the dynamic field, it just looks like this:

```
{value: "1234"}
```

Compared with a static input field that is defined within the template:

```
{$viewValue: "", $modelValue: "", $$rawModelValue: "", $validators: {…}, $asyncValidators: {…}, …}$$animate: {on: ƒ, off: ƒ, pin: ƒ, enabled: ƒ, cancel: ƒ, …}$$attr: Attributes {$attr: {…}, $$element: JQLite(1), type: "text", name: "giftDescription", class: "uk-input uk-height-small", …}$$classCache: {ng-valid: true, ng-invalid: false, ng-valid-minlength: true, ng-valid-maxlength: true}$$currentValidationRunId: 8$$element: JQLite [input.uk-input.uk-height-small.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-empty.ng-valid-minlength.ng-vali…]$$exceptionHandler: ƒ (exception, cause)$$lastCommittedViewValue: ""$$ngModelGet: ƒ (s,l,a,i)$$ngModelSet: ƒ (s,v,l)$$parentForm: {$$controls: Array(16), $error: {…}, $$success: {…}, $pending: undefined, $name: "build.justTest.view", …}$$parse: ƒ $parse(exp, interceptorFn)$$parsedNgModel: ƒ (s,l,a,i)$$parsedNgModelAssign: ƒ (s,v,l)$$parserValid: undefined$$pendingDebounce: null$$q: ƒ $Q(resolver)$$rawModelValue: ""$$success: {minlength: true, maxlength: true}$$timeout: ƒ timeout(fn, delay, invokeApply)$asyncValidators: {}$dirty: false$error: {}$formatters: [ƒ]$invalid: false$modelValue: ""$name: "giftDescription"$options: ModelOptions {$$options: {…}}$parsers: []$pending: undefined$pristine: true$render: ƒ ()$touched: false$untouched: true$valid: true$validators: {minlength: ƒ, maxlength: ƒ}$viewChangeListeners: [ƒ]$viewValue: ""value: "12345678910"$$scope: Scope {$$childTail: ChildScope, $$childHead: ChildScope, $$nextSibling: null, $$watchers: Array(86), $$listeners: {…}, …}__proto__: Object
```

Can anyone tell me why is `$valid` not defined on the input from the directive and

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to add this following to your directive definition ?

```
...,
require: '^form',
restrict: 'EA',
...
```

I always thought that was automatically done with input. But when you use directive you have to define this.

Then you can access to the form in the link function of your directive as following :

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, myForm) {...}
```